# Angular Editable Text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a code where a user clicks a button on the screen, the user can see a paragraph. I want that paragraph to be editable. For example, the user should be able to write additional stuff in it. There was a `readonly` part in my code and I removed it, but it is still not editable. How can I achieve this?

[image]
HTML Code:

```
<div class="content fuse-white ml-24 mr-8 h-100-p" fusePerfectScrollbar>
        <div class="label-list">
            <p>
                Label Info: 

                <span>
                    {{_stickerData?.StickerData}}
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you try by applying `contenteditable="true"` attribute on your `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, as outlined from this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

You  have to set the

> contenteditable

attribute on the paragraph element to make it editable.

Bind the paragraph attribute with Boolean value so that when you click the button, set the Boolean to True which will trigger the content to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Span Tag to Texttera.

app.component.html:

```
<textarea>{{_stickerData?.StickerData}}</texttera>
```

app.component.ts:

```
_stickerData.StickerData: string = "Text in the Input Field"
```